# Which connector is it?

Tags: connector, identification

Could you please help me to identify this connector ? Could you please advise me a reference for a corresponding mating connector ?

Additionnal information:

- 24 pins.
- 0.5 mm pitch.

[image]

**Edit:** Successfully solved thanks to your help. It is a AXK5S24047YG connector, to be used with a AXK6S24447YG mating pair.

Comment: I usually go to mouser.com, connectors, filter by pitch and scroll until you find something similar. Not that hard, I easily found iPhone FPCs, for example (0.35mm pitch)

Comment: What device did you find this connector in ? If possible, mention its function too. It will help narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: looks to be 0.5mm pitch

Comment: Check Samtec's website

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be a Panasonic P5KS Series connector, likely the AXK5S24047YG, or a similar one from the series. A mating connector for this one would be an AXK6S24447YG or similar.

See [the datasheet](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e_download/control/connector/base-base/catalog/con_eng_p5k.pdf) and the [obligatory Digikey link](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electric-works/AXK5S24047YG/255-3233-1-ND/2793966#images).

[image: Image from Digikey]

[Obligatory Digikey link](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electric-works/AXK5S24047YG/255-3233-1-ND/2793966#images)

---

I found this by searching Digikey, going to the Connectors, Interconnects category, then Rectangular Connectors - Arrays etc, then punched in the known values into the search: 24 pins, 2 rows, 0.5mm pitch, Center Strip Contacts.

I have no affiliation with Digikey, I just find their parametric search good.

Comment: And a very good feature of Digikey is that it shows the mating products (receptacles, pins, etc) for a specific connector. PS: Not a Digikey advertisement.

Comment: Many thanks ! You identified the connector.